# Error in launching a task on an Android phone

Tags: android

i was launching an activity and this code has shown:

[image]

I'm just know a little bit about coding so if is there anyone can help me with detail instructions to fix this problem, i will very appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to launch an App that you don't have permission to launch. Edit your question and explain more about what you are trying to do. Your tags are very strange: why `adb` and `javascript`?

Comment: I have said in description, i just know a little bit about coding. I don't know what to tag, so i tag the same as the problem i saw before.